# Labelling (pinning) points in a plot automatically

Tags: pgfplots

I have a scatter plot that I am generating based on some data stored in comma-separated format. I need to add a label to each point: this information is available as part of the `.csv` file as it's used as the row labels. Currently, the approach I have is to plot the points automatically but to add the labels by hand:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Label,x,y,angle
a,1,1,0
b,2,2.5,0
c,3,2.9,0
d,4,4.1,-90
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table
      [col sep = comma, x = x, y = y] {\jobname.csv};
    \node[pin = a] at (axis cs:1,1) {};
    \node[pin = b] at (axis cs:2,2.5) {};
    \node[pin = c] at (axis cs:3,2.9) {};
    \node[pin = -90:d] at (axis cs:4,4.1) {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Clearly this is not very efficient: ideally, I'd like to read the information from the stored table. This needs some form of mapping, but from the documentation for `pgfplots(table)` there seems to be a lack of a row-wise function to do that.

Is it possible to write a (relatively simply) mapping which will add the nodes, picking up the *x* and *y* values plus the label and angle (or perhaps wider 'pin modification') from the `.csv` file? My table is not too long: maximum of about a dozen rows.

Comment: In my real case the _y_-axis values are calculated at point of use, but I should be able to pre-load the table and make a new column to account for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make the label available using `point meta = explicit symbolic` in the `\addplot` options and `meta = Label` in the `table` options. The angle can be made available using `visualization depends on = \thisrow{Angle} \as \angle`. Then you can create the pins using `nodes near coords`:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Label,x,y,angle
a,1,1,90
b,2,2.5,90
c,3,2.9,90
d,4,4.1,-90
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[visualization depends on = \thisrow{angle} \as \angle]
    \addplot +[
            nodes near coords=,
            point meta = explicit symbolic,
            every node near coord/.style = {
                anchor = center, pin = {\angle:\pgfplotspointmeta}
            }
        ] table
      [col sep = comma, x = x, y = y, meta = Label
      ] {\jobname.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent: no mapping needed (I think I could sort that out, but it probably would not be worth the effort!)